# Spring Rest - Post multiple files

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, multipartform-data, spring-rest

Using Spring Boot 2.1.8, I have two methods in a Rest Controller that expect a single file and multiple files respectively. These are the method signatures:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping("/uploadMultipleFiles")
    public List<FileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files);

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping("/upload")
public FileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file);
```

The single upload works just perfect. I am managing to load a single file from a web client, Postman v7.25.0, and from Swagger 2.

But the multiple file method only works when uploading files from Postman, returning a 400 http error code. Therefore, it does not even enter the method.

The error message in both cases (web client or Swagger) is the same:

```
can't parse JSON.  Raw result:
Missing or unreadable multipart file in request
```

This is the request headers when calling to /uploadMultipleFiles through Swagger (getting error):
[image]

This is the request headers when calling /uploadMultipleFiles from Postman (works fine):
[image]

This is the request headers when calling /upload from Postman (works fine):
[image]

This is the request headers when calling /upload through Swagger (works fine):
[image]

Firstly I thought that Content-Type might have something to do with my problem. But Swagger sends always application/json, and it works with the single upload endpoint.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with file uploads using multipartfile, you should set the content type of the request to `multipart/form-data`. The screenshot shows that Postman is using `multipart/form-data` and not `application/json`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The question then is: how do I tell Swagger to set the Content-Type to multipart/form-data? And one comment: the last image shows how the single file upload works fine from swagger (setting Content-Type to application/json).

Comment: If you're using the OAS3 standard in Swagger, you can use this: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

They use `application/json` for their example and you can replace that with the content type on the answer.

Without looking at the request body, I unfortunately can't say why it works like that with Swagger